How to use template of Eigen::Vector?
Is there a base type of vector as MatrixBase in eigen?
template <typename Derived>
void test(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& R, const double deg, const Vector3d& u) {

    R = Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::Identity(3, 3);
    Vector3d u_ = u / u.norm();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Vector3d v = R.col(i);
        R.col(i) = v * cos(deg) + u_.cross(v) * sin(deg) + (1 - cos(deg)) * (u_.dot(v)) * u_;
    }

}

I have a method taking MatrixXd/MatrixXf and Vector3d/Vector3f as inputs, I know I can make the first one as template type,but how to use the template of Vector3d ?

"How to use template of Eigen::Vector?..." Did you read the documentation for Eigen? As Vector3d seems to be an alias for typedef Matrix< double, 3, 1 >. Note finding and reading documentation is important and essential part of programming.

Related: C++/Eigen - How to pass a general vector as parameter?
